# Find (and replace) styles in Word using C#

Tags: c#, replace, ms-word, find, styles

I'm coping with finding (and eventually replacing) some text by styles in Word.
The idea is, let's say, to convert all "Heading 2" paragraphs to "Heading 1".
But I don't know how to find ONLY style, regardless of its contents. 
Can anyone point me in right direction?

```
var app = Globals.ThisAddIn.Application;
var dok = app.ActiveDocument;
Word.Range rng = dok.Content;
var a = rng.Find;
  a.ClearFormatting();
  a.Format = true;
  ...
```

And this is where I need to point to a style, but don't know how.

Answer (score 0):

OK, I've found it... It's this line:

```
a.set_Style(dok.Styles["Heading 2"]);
```